# Convert PDF to Html or any type of image

Tags: c#, html, image, pdf

Is there any way to convert pdf to html or any type of image using c# ?
I have tried PDFReader.dll and itextsharp.dll, but I couldn't figure out.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

How about the open source suite [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org). It has interfaces for a good number of programming languages among which is C#. ImageMagick can read and write images in various formats.

A C# application wrapper of ImageMagick core is available [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/imagemagickapp/).

An example on converting a PDF file using ImageMagick C# interface is given [here](http://magick.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Convert%20PDF&referringTitle=Documentation).

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into the following:

http://www.sautinsoft.com/products/pdf-focus/convert-pdf-to-html-in-dotnet.php

Looks pretty straightforward:

```
SautinSoft.PdfFocus f = new SautinSoft.PdfFocus();
f.OpenPdf(@"c:\Odyssey.pdf");
f.ToHtml(@"c:\Odyssey.html");
```

> PDF Focus .Net generates HTML5 document with CSS and images. Another
>   point of interest is that it can generate HTML documents with images
>   encoded by base-64 algorithm. Given this fact, it's possible to
>   convert PDF to HTML completely in memory.

Comment: Thank for reply, I used trial version of SautinSoft, it converts only first 3 pages, If I could convert pdf splited into small documents with 3 pages, it will also work